# Designing asynchronous methods in TDD

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, tdd

Hi I am new to TDD and just want to start exploring.

I have a use case "RegisterAccount" and it is going to take in some registration info from user (let's name it "RegistrationInfo"), send it to a server, get the success state and respond to user (success, fail, or connection problem).

Now I start with a test case to test that when the registration success, the use case is going to inform the UI to show a message of success. So I will have:

```
verify(registrationPresenter, times(1)).showRegistrationSuccessed();
```

as the result that I want (BTW I am using Mockito for mocking object). At the same time, I will have a registration info object, which is not mocked:

```
RegistrationInfo info = new RegistrationInfo(username, password, email);
```

and the mocked presenter together and registration service class:

```
RegistrationPresenter registrationPresenter = Mockito.mock(RegistrationPresenter);

RegistrationService registrationService = Mockito.mock(RegistrationService.class);
```

Now when I started to think to link these 3 pieces together, I dunno whether I have to make this service call **synchronous** or **asynchronous**.

Any sane developer knew that we MUST NOT place any network I/O in main thread interrupting the UI rendering, therefore this use case at some point need to be shifted to background (thread, executor, asynctask, etc., etc.).

First question I have is whether I should design this use case as synchronous and let the service layer handles the asynchronous call? Or design the use case itself in asynchronous manner?

Second question is whether the asynchronous methods are better implemented using **callback** or **FutureTask** from java concurrent utility (or any other way)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html

Here the presenter implements the "use case" logic and the async implementation is done at repository level.

If you apply clean/hexagonal arch concepts:

http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/

Repositories and interactors (use case implementations) apply the async. Presenter uses interactors and manages its events.

If your presenter listens to view events ("handle view async") why not do the same with use case/repository events and "handle the use case async"?

This examples have distincts callback implementations: the first defines and implements its own callbacks and the second uses subscriptor/observer and thread control.

Hope it helps you!